# Extract correct union type at runtime inside extraced function

Tags: typescript, xstate

I try to create typings for events that will be processed in xstate. 
Currently xstate calls the `processChangeEvent` function with a `DefinedEvent` parameter.  This typing can't be changed.
The `processChangeEvent` should always be called with a change event therefore I would like to achieve a way to check if the given event is a change event or else throw an error.

Everything works inside an if statement. The typescript compilers realizes the `CHANGE` event type and therefor I can access the `value` attribute.

```
export type Event<TType, TData = unknown> = { type: TType } & TData;
export type Value<TType> = { value: TType };
export type DefinedEvents = Event<'INC'> | Event<'DEC'> | Event<'CHANGE', Value<number>>;

function processChangeEventOK(event: DefinedEvents) {
    if (event.type === 'CHANGE') {
            return event.value; // NO COMPILER ERROR :-)
    } else {
        throw new Error(`Event must be of type CHANGE but is ${event.type}`);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need this a lot of times. Therefore I tried to extract the logic inside the `processEventOrThrowException` function. I know that somehow the callback must be differently typed `Event<T`but I wouldn't know how?

```js
function processChangeEvent(event: DefinedEvents) {
    return processEventOrThrowException(event, 'CHANGE', (castedEvent) => {
        return castedEvent.value; // COMPILER ERROR :-(
    });
}

function processEventOrThrowException<TType>(event: Event<any>, type: string, callback: (castedEvent: Event<TType, unknown>) => any) {
    if (event.type === type) {
        return callback(event);
    } else {
        throw new Error(`Event must be of type CHANGE but is ${event.type}`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define the following helper types and [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
type EventTypes = DefinedEvents['type'];
type EventOfType<T extends EventTypes> = Extract<DefinedEvents, { type: T }>
function isEventOfType<T extends EventTypes>(
  event: DefinedEvents, 
  type: T
): event is EventOfType<T> {
  return event.type === type;
}
```

This takes your `DefinedEvents` discriminated union and abstracts the operation of checking the `type` property to distinguish between members of the union, using the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility type.  Armed with these, I'd define `processEventOrThrowException()` like this:

```
function processEventOrThrowException<T extends EventTypes, R>(
  event: DefinedEvents,
  type: T,
  callback: (castedEvent: EventOfType<T>) => R
) {
  if (isEventOfType(event, type)) {
    return callback(event);
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Event must be of type ${type} but is ${event.type}`);
  }
}
```

That's generic in both the type `T` of the `type` argument, and the type `R` of the callback return value.  Now your `processChangeEvent()` should work as expected:

```
function processChangeEvent(event: DefinedEvents) {
  return processEventOrThrowException(event, 'CHANGE', (castedEvent) => {
    return castedEvent.value
  });
}
```

and because of the `R` type in `processEventOrThrowException()`, the return type of `processChangeEvent()` is inferred to be `number`:

```
const val = processChangeEvent({ type: "CHANGE", value: Math.PI });
console.log(val.toFixed(2)) // 3.14

processChangeEvent({ type: "DEC" }); // Error: Event must be of type CHANGE but is DEC
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#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-k2KBK2vasuR5R8VWgdVGU1Qc9QNCAjQVX8qAEFoOm6XoBAjEAo0A1tU3IUDKBrCD6zw6MqgFAJBkvC9ryvCF4HhRdaM0JUoLVV93y-H9gV4fQACI2k6HohIEWigiQABZUQtQFAAFPITAY44WOAKBFBcCABRcRQPzxWihUUAAxOJbmSPEACYKyQAB6eykAAZgFABGAAWaVr0458eM-b9NjxATfSE2oiiE1TrAcpyGHHRQJjjTY5wXfdl1XH1kFErClz3A9wu8vAr2MIA)

Comment: Hi @jcalz. Thanks a lot for your very elegant solution. This would perfectly answer my question. However one thing I missed to mention is that I have several statemaschines that can send events. This means that DefinedEvents would be of a different type in another statemaschine. For example Maschine1Events = Event<'INC'> | Event<'ACTION'>. But I would love to use the processEventOrThrowException for both kind of maschine events.

Comment: Is there a way to send a link to the modified playground. The url created in the TypeScriptPlayground is to large for a comment and tinyUrl is not allowed

Comment: Do you ever have two events with the same `type` but with different data?   If not, then just make one big discriminated union for `DefinedEvents` and use it for `processEventOrThrowException()`.  It's fine if some other code just uses a subset of the elements of that union.  In any case I really can only answer the question as stated.  Either you should accept this answer (or the other one by @Guilhermevrs) and post a follow-up question, or edit the current question to match exactly what you need, with enough of a [mcve] to be answerable.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again. A discriminated union isn't what I want, as then the method has to be changed with every new event. Therefor I followed your advice and posted the follow up question as a "hopefully" minimal reproducible example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143431/typescript-compiler-infering-type-with-generics I believe I am close. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

[Link for the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKEDOmCWAjAG2ABVlhM4BeOAcgEkA5AYRrgB9aARAURfdqYAJAIIMA4txoBuAFAzQkWAjJxuAN2AA7GAB5ipFHFAwtAEwoZs%20IgfIAaOMU4BDGM6pwArpoDWmiADumgB8HgDeyigAXI62cAC%20cABkji5usgrQ8EiGAGrOBJ7Aerah1BFqBUUx%20irxsvLgWZGonMAAZjiawKbqWjCYekYgJprm6Fi4hCRkFNSWUzazZTJwa47Do%20M0QqISrAD8q%20snfdo6OyLikg75hcUMngC2eMBQwcHHJ2sxZ7rEnxk7W8AGMYDgIJo4GAoBAQeRMEwABbOTQAc2AfwAFMANNoYm1Ot1eniBgBKOBhL5wKDAGCeKBQmFwhF-ADyUGISNhAW4IHhYHBkJxpIclz2NzgWJBzkwJhJ-QplFCVO%2061p9MZcBlcp6fwAdJV7lI4AB6U1wJhsgCyaDoABluAAlVROp1sl1RAC0WOp8TJsnicmBmjBEKZsPh2HZnO5gT5AqFmiGxjMFkm1hmKEwwRF-QJHS6etJmAcOWANQcMoIBDwzhBPhi0tl8r%20BaJxf6gwBStCqMQFNV6xBkLlcBwiOgtLBfw8OPbRYV2kwZJiqAncEJi7%203bKoVx-X15aolGo5epOHaUonTCnwBnpLz2jJg%20pJw1DKh1dr9Z8T5gAZ%20kYBCYKgQ5qjAcYBHA3TQdwUCwlAWIAAazk8nhjq8cAQFex67NccB4J48AbgAJGEB7aEeZDxMhgEnEG8RAA)

```js
export type PossibleTypes = 'INC' | 'DEC' | 'CHANGE';

export type Event < TType extends PossibleTypes, TData = unknown > = {
  type: TType
} & TData;
export type Value < TType > = {
  value: TType
};

export type DefinedEvents < T extends PossibleTypes = PossibleTypes > =
  T extends 'CHANGE' ?
  Event < 'CHANGE', Value < Number >>
  : Event < T >

  function processChangeEvent(event: DefinedEvents) {
    return processEventOrThrowException(event, 'CHANGE', (castedEvent) => {
      return castedEvent.value; // COMPILER ERROR :-(
    });
  }

function processEventOrThrowException < T extends PossibleTypes > (event: DefinedEvents, type: T, callback: (castedEvent: DefinedEvents < T > ) => any) {
  const isCorrectEvent = (e: DefinedEvents): e is DefinedEvents < T > => event.type === type
  if (isCorrectEvent(event)) {
    return callback(event);
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Event must be of type CHANGE but is ${event.type}`);
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

- List all the possible types
- Use the conditional typing to define the `DefinedEvents`
- Use a type predicate to identify if `event` is of the correct type