# Typescript compiler infering type with generics

Tags: typescript

I try to achieve a generic `isEventOfType` function. In multiple places events from a x-state statemachine are defined (see `Maschine1Events`, `Maschine2Events`). When processing events x-states can only provide a `Maschine1Events` or `Maschine2Events` but can't tell exactly which event is processed.

I therefore need a method to check if the event is of a type that I expect. For example that the 'CHANGE' event is provided.

This example is fully functional, but what I fail to understand is why inside the `fWithoutGeneric` function the types can't be infered.

```js
    export type Event<TType, TData = unknown> = { type: TType } & TData;
    export type Value<TType> = { value: TType };

    type Maschine1Events = Event<'INC'> | Event<'DEC'> | Event<'CHANGE', Value<number>>;
    type Maschine2Events = Event<'INC', Value<number> | Event<'SEND_MESSAGE', Value<string>>;

    type EventTypes<T extends Event<unknown>> = T['type'];
    type EventOfType<T extends Event<unknown>, U extends EventTypes<T> = EventTypes<T>> = Extract<T, { type: U }>;
    function isEventOfType<T extends Event<unknown>, U extends EventTypes<T> = EventTypes<T>>(
        event: T,
        type: U
    ): event is EventOfType<T, U> {
        return event.type === type;
    }

    function fWithGenerics(event: Maschine1Events) {
        if (isEventOfType<Maschine1Events, 'CHANGE'>(event, 'CHANGE')) {
            const a: Event<'CHANGE', Value<number>> = event;
        }
    }
    function fWithOutGenerics(event: Maschine2Events) {
        if (isEventOfType(event, 'SEND_MESSAGE')) {
            const a: Event<'SEND_MESSAGE', Value<string>> = event; //Why can't this be infered
        }
    }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBNJBvAsAKCU0ksCyAGhjnnhAB4wD2ATgC5JMCeMyAogG4TBMAPABVhHCABokwgCIgmIJAF4kAV2ABrYHQDuwAHzKMrcQC5pYzkgC%20SAGTS5CgNwVKNesxNWAaiAA2qhAilhCGKuhIPAFB5qLiNq7YbnjsVgCyIFDwABYAlsAQAIy8-ExQRqUCggDkAJIAcgDCNYYAPkhVQjUyXC3tnXzVNU0AEgCCDQDiXDVSfoHBwKpgAEYQDPr6SZTeyJnZ%20YUATF0VKl21jS3zMUsr65tIHZc1AMpcDTIA%20ulcb29xjM5kgFkFBFAmAwCgBzLZJFJ7QZlUJQERIGhMfgAEwql3UWl0BnC0gA2jU0hAagBdHaUSnIgQAeQAZqF0ZicXihkICdo9PopABVDHULHAXGMpiokQkroy4RbSpihgIITCKSRSnmEXWbaIlnqeBMPJ0YBIPJQLqs9nCUXiyX4zT8gzC%201cqUKuU8r36AAUiN2EB5cQkgfpZiQQsRAEpzMGyhbuWUbeIRMLDFhcLtKAwIExVAxzQmBAA6BlKSt7Ol4aw4A1Gk1mpAsgDqeSYOSm-A2eXgUD9JaY5gOuQKxTOMfI2ZzFpZSD9lutbLTo6OE55UCkIwm01m-qH27Gk2BManWdns-gZshSBA5lex73ILB9zWGyVKiHNZzdZnNgbYBjVNc02w7HImVUJhu0KaF%200HEMkDXcdTk3c9wzwPJ50XK0eVTTgELKbcPi%20X5-kBU90P-S8kGvYBb3vKVahIn4-gBIFZluRYIShWFPwxHlnCQAB6YTWxyNhaJAYAKVYfIKnWC1gBZDYIGxDCAP-P9axwawgA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be inclined to give `isEventOfType()` the following signature:

```
function isEventOfType<E extends { type: string }, T extends E['type']>(
    event: E,
    type: T
): event is Extract<E, { type: T }> {
    return event.type === type;
}
```

I simplified the parameters a bit and removed the [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) for the second parameter.  I don't know what the point was of those, but unless you need them they are probably just a distraction.

The big change here is that the `E` type of the `event` parameter is now [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `{type: string}` instead of `{type: unknown}`.  The `string` gives the compiler a hint to infer a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) for the type `T` of the `type` parameter (see [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) for details about about how inference of literal types happens).

Now the code works as you expect, I think:

```
function m1(event: Maschine1Events) {
    if (isEventOfType(event, 'CHANGE')) {
        event.value.toFixed(2); // okay
    } else {
        event // {type: "INC"} | {type: "DEC"}
    }
}
function m2(event: Maschine2Events) {
    if (isEventOfType(event, 'SEND_MESSAGE')) {
        event.value.toUpperCase(); // okay
    } else {
        event.value.toFixed(2); // okay
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-SSDfAk0JaXAAETxBLl2RpQRl8vZatqv1qtUPbBPF5vRr9F0hI3uE0Dc0+60+W32z6jH6mfu4N3rTY7PYHL0+uDWv1F2VBowhgCqYBQUAS7mABLjieTqfTmcBObzW9JO73wBD4cj0dj8ZLt4zraqNIQA)